# Can a non-touchable image be added over a Google map?

Tags: android, image, google-maps

I would like to add a logo over my google map in my android app, but i dont want it to interfere with map dragging. If the dragging starts where the logo is, the dragging doesnt take place.

Is there a way to add the image in such manner that touching it i actually touch the map?

This is the way i am adding the ImageView:

```
          final ImageView tv = new ImageView(AppContext);
          tv.setTag(tt);
          tv.setId(ctlid);              
          dh.addView(tv, params);
```

I am not setting any touch listeners, but the image still interferes between the touch and the google-map.

Comment: make the image enabled to false

Comment: Thanks that worked. :)

Comment: ill add it as answer, could you check it? :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as what I comment there, make image enabled to false

```
image.setEnabled(false); // java code
```

or

```
android:enabled="false" // xml code
```